# Need to extract only Modulus value from Bean Shell Sampler Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

In my Bean Shell Sampler i am getting response as

Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 22295351891298217229975679072351263454572804823888397394956934480688545098388363434555311921650592166059251017638546278442305958792511628365321549674368487249258317999232492062784515102404906734978121435799114700302881045885988703962970888009290777606595760751230036638945779986258956916131307234869683993065702144540870733479633460269689089976061715241046980179651894991519601546098863574672792649655278518708922038045203420614818093220439077000089729610115783652292803355176127125944925842204444536282480600674854449097908926668384181326756503446116301460522215211454108585731728225508829847198093781511594519426983
  public exponent: 65537

I just need to extract the value in the modulus field. How can we do it in Jmeter ? Help is useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Switch to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language
2. Use the code like below to extract your "modulus" value using Regular Expression [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) like

   ```
   def response = 'Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits modulus: 22295351891298217229975679072351263454572804823888397394956934480688545098388363434555311921650592166059251017638546278442305958792511628365321549674368487249258317999232492062784515102404906734978121435799114700302881045885988703962970888009290777606595760751230036638945779986258956916131307234869683993065702144540870733479633460269689089976061715241046980179651894991519601546098863574672792649655278518708922038045203420614818093220439077000089729610115783652292803355176127125944925842204444536282480600674854449097908926668384181326756503446116301460522215211454108585731728225508829847198093781511594519426983 public exponent: 65537'

   def matcher = response =~ /modulus: (.+?) public/

   if (matcher.find()) {
       log.info(matcher.group(1))
   }
   ```

References:

- [Using Regular Expressions in Groovy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/groovy.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

---

Beanshell equivalent just in case:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


String response = "Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits modulus: 22295351891298217229975679072351263454572804823888397394956934480688545098388363434555311921650592166059251017638546278442305958792511628365321549674368487249258317999232492062784515102404906734978121435799114700302881045885988703962970888009290777606595760751230036638945779986258956916131307234869683993065702144540870733479633460269689089976061715241046980179651894991519601546098863574672792649655278518708922038045203420614818093220439077000089729610115783652292803355176127125944925842204444536282480600674854449097908926668384181326756503446116301460522215211454108585731728225508829847198093781511594519426983 public exponent: 65537";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("modulus: (.+?) public");
Matcher m = p.matcher(response);
if (m.find()){
    log.info(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T. Is there a way to read the full response from Bean Shell Sampler. In your code, you have hard coded it. But in my Jmeter it will be randomly generated. I need to capture that randomly generated modulus value .

Comment: If you have 2 Beanshell Samplers one after another and want to use 1st sampler's response data in 2nd one you can do it like: `String response = ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString();`. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T. I have also tried the same , but got error as Error processing JSON content in JSON Extractor, message: Could not parse token starting at position 42. But the response i am getting from Bean Shell Sampler is not Json Response.